# SQL UNPIVOT TABLE IN SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

hi to all i want my all columns header name into a one columns so please help me on this query.
here my table structure

I have table like this Named tblInfo

```
| ID |  Name |Email ID|Age |Gender |
```

I want to get the result as

```
|Columns|

ID
Name
Email ID
Age`enter code here
Gender
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: i am using SQL SERVER

Answer (score 2):

Why you are not using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` view ?

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = <table_name>
```

Other way is to use `sys.all_objects`

```
SELECT c.name
FROM sys.all_objects b
     JOIN sys.all_columns c ON c.object_id = b.object_id
WHERE b.name = <table_name>
      AND b.type = 'U';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer its help me.

Comment: @vipulverma read https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/08/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/ or https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers